# Radio looping not working - using jquery to access checked value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to build a quiz app. I am specifically looking to debug the checkanswer function below. It seems that the radio input looping is not working. What is the issue?

The last line is where I am facing issues. The for loop is correcting recognizing the name of the form. But is not able to loop for some reason.

```js
var questions = {
  'question1': {
    'sticker': "images/lion.jpg",
    'question': "Do male lions hunt prey or protect territory, what is more common?",
    'name': 'question1',
    'choices': ['Hunt', 'Protect', 'Both', 'Neither'],
    'correctanswer': 'Protect'
  },
}

function wildcatsActivate() {
  for (const question in questions) {
    $('#sticker').append(`<img src=${questions[question].sticker}>`);
    $('#question').append(`<br><h3>${questions[question].question}</h3>`)
    $('#choices').append(`
        <form name="form" id="question1form">
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
             value=${questions[question].choices[0]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[0]}>Protect territory</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
             value=${questions[question].choices[1]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[1]}>Hunt prey</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
             value=${questions[question].choices[2]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[2]}>Both are common</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
            value=${questions[question].choices[3]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[3]}>Neither</label><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="answercheck()">
        </form>
        `)
    $("#question1form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

}

function answercheck() {
  $('.answercomment').remove();
  for (const question in questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.form.questions[question].name.length; i++) {
      $('#answer').append(`<p>${document.form.questions[question].name.checked}</p>`);

    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is incomplete. Please edit it and make a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. I am fairly new to SO, still learning best practices. I agree the above approach and code is not optimal. By the way I found out the issue in my answercheck function. Turns out that I wasn't getting the elements properly. I created a variable ele=document.getelementsbyname and looped through that and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I would use querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByName - or what I did which is jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You may mean something like this

- Your field access in incorrect and VERY complicated
- You have the same ID for all question forms. That will come back and bite you
- you have radios, no need to loop the values

```js
var questions = {
  'question1': {
    'sticker': "images/lion.jpg",
    'question': "Do male lions hunt prey or protect territory, what is more common?",
    'name': 'question1',
    'choices': ['Hunt', 'Protect', 'Both', 'Neither'],
    'correctanswer': 'Protect'
  },
}

function wildcatsActivate() {
  for (const question in questions) {
    $('#sticker').append(`<img src=${questions[question].sticker}>`);
    $('#question').append(`<br><h3>${questions[question].question}</h3>`)
    $('#choices').append(`
        <form name="form" id="${question}form">
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
             value=${questions[question].choices[0]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[0]}>Protect territory</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
             value=${questions[question].choices[1]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[1]}>Hunt prey</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
             value=${questions[question].choices[2]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[2]}>Both are common</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name=${questions[question].name} 
            value=${questions[question].choices[3]}>
            <label for=${questions[question].choices[3]}>Neither</label><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="answercheck()">
        </form>
        `)
    $("#question1form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

}

function answercheck() {
  $('.answercomment').remove();
  for (let question in questions) {
    const radVal = $(`#${question}form input[name=${question}]:checked`).val();
    $('#answer').append(`<p>${radVal}</p>`)
  }
}
wildcatsActivate()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="sticker"></span>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id="answer"></div>
<div id="choices"></div>
```